# How to query Firestore from client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am make security rule for Firebase app with authentication.

I want only user be able access his own user document.

I have this security rule:

```
  match /users/{uid} {
  allow read, update: if request.auth.uid == uid;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
```

But when I run client code, it give error:

> [Firestore]: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or
>   insufficient permissions., cause=null}

In client code I check if document with user uid already exist (if it not exist, I write data to firestore):

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .getDocuments();
documents = result.documents;
if (documents.isEmpty) {
…
```

Why I get this error?

I have read https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query and it say `db.collection("stories").where("author", "==", user.uid).get()` is valid.

Comment: could be that you haven't added the dependencies correctly ?

Comment: @Abby Thanks for reply! I have add correct

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user is not authenticated when you are doing this request, are you sure that you implemented the [authentication engine](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) + authenticated the user first?

Comment: Thanks for reply! No. user is authenticate correct first. I am sure

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not match your rules.  The query is asking for all the documents where the document field `uid` is the same as `user.uid`.  But your rule is allowing read access to documents with the document ID is the same as the user's UID.  These are not the same thing.  Query is dealing with a **document field** called `uid`, and the rules is dealing with the **document ID**.  The query and the rule must match.  Since you haven't said anything about the structure of your documents, or what specifically you're trying to achieve, it's not possible to recommend and alternative.  In any event, your query must match the rule, or it will fail every time.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I want check if document with `document id == uid` exist in `users/` collection. How I can do?

Comment: Then you need to change your query to do what you're saying.  You will have to build a DocumentReference to the document using its ID, and get() it.